# Calculate percentage of specific columns in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

[image: Example of database]

I am trying to calculate the percentage of all of the numeric columns,from greeting_msg to ask_alt_number. I am able to get the correct percentage when there is only one record, but I cannot get the correct result as I add more records.

Code example
Query:

```
$sumGreeting = $dbcon->prepare(`SELECT SUM(greeting_msg + provide_agent_name + clear_and_aud + confirm_caller_name + confirm_caller_tel + ask_alt_number) AS SumGrt  FROM table`);
$sumGreeting->execute();
```

Code:

```
$initRows = 0;
while ($row = $sumGreeting->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
     $initRows = $row[`SumGrt`];
     $result = ($initRows/12)*100;
     echo $result.` %; 
}
```

Any help will do.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, post your code, this way we can help you.

Comment: Show your attempt for single record

Comment: The section is out of 12 points

Comment: Please update your question and provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than posting updates in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a group by clause to get calculated sum per coach , agent_name ..., Right now you are  using an aggregate function `sum()` in absence of `group by` so your whole table is treated as single group and aggregation is applied on all records, you need to group them by specifying your grouping columns in select and group by clause

```
SELECT coach, agent_name, reference, campaign_name
    SUM(greeting_msg + provide_agent_name + clear_and_aud + confirm_caller_name + confirm_caller_tel + ask_alt_number) AS SumGrt  
FROM table
GROUP BY coach, agent_name, reference, campaign_name
```

Also put your query inside single quotes in `prepare('query')` not in backticks

Comment: Awesome. This worked, I am getting the correct result. How can I show only the most recent percentage?

Comment: @pulaS29 without viewing the actual results i can't exactly tell you, It would be good if you can ask a new question and include all the details for your issue